# Looking at something realistically

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I wonder if you let me know in the following fictional scenario, the phrasal verb **look at** works properly or there is a better verb to phrase my sentence:

> It isn't realistic to expect people to work for such little money. So let's **look at** the matter more realistically.

I guess the verb **consider** can work too, but it would give a formal tone to this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Look at" is fine.

You could also have "consider", or "analyse", if a single verb is prefered.